# generate exchange CSR , exchange 2007 UCC. SSL CERT

Tags: exchange-2007, ssl-certificate, csr, ucc

I want to make sure I am going this correctly.

**machine name**: win2k8ex1.

**certificate:**

**common name:** owa.x.com

**subject alternative domains:**

autodiscover.x.com

mail.x.com

WIN2K8EX1

WIN2K8EX1.x.LOCAL

**when generating the CSR, i want to:**

New-ExchangeCertificate -GenerateRequest -SubjectName "c=US, o=x Inc., cn=owa.x.com" -DomainName mail.x.com,WIN2K8EX1,WIN2K8EX!.x.local,autodiscover.x.com -privatekeyexportable $true -Path c:\certificates\mcert.txt

does this look correct?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well there is a ! in WIN2K8EX!, which I am assuming should be a 1, but aside from that, looks good.